# Querying "highest" RowKey

Tags: azure-table-storage

I use a RowKey which is a number (as string). 
How can I get the highest number (RowKey) with a query ?

Max operator is not supported. But is there another possibility ?

Answer (score 0):

All entries in table are ordered by PartitionKey and then by RowKey. So your highest number should always be the last item (if you are using the same PartitionKey for all entries).
Also you can you can get all data by using .ToList() and then call .Max() method. But this method could be inefficient and slow if you got lots of entries.